# How can I set what is called "PrintTitleRows" in Excel Interop using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel-interop, epplus, epplus-4

I've got this Excel Interop code:

```
_xlSheetFillRateByDCByLocation.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = String.Format("${0}:${0}", BYDCBYLOC_HEADING_ROW);
```

I want to accomplish the same with EPPlus.

I tried this:

```
locationWorksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatColumns.Rows = BYDCBYLOC_HEADING_ROW;
```

...but "RepeatColumns.Rows" is a readonly property, and thus cannot be assigend to.

I found this:

```
locationWorksheet.PrinterSettings.ShowHeaders = true;
```

...but I don't know if I'm barking up the wrong tree with that.

What is the analogue in EPPlus to Excel Interop's PrintTitleRows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give it a proper `ExcelAddress` object like this:

```
worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatRows = new ExcelAddress("$1:$1");
worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatColumns = new ExcelAddress("$A:$A");
```

Comment: When using 'worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatRows = new ExcelAddress("$1:$1");' and then attempting to print from within Excel, I am getting the error "print titles must be contiguous and complete rows or columns." Have you heard anything about this issue?